# AS3 - How to find TWO biggest numbers in Array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cc

Was wondering how I could find the TWO biggest numbers in an Array using as3 and Flash. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is comprised of just numbers, then you can do the following:

```
myArray.sort(Array.NUMERIC);

var biggest:Number = myArray[myArray.length-1];
var nextBiggest:Number = myArray[myArray.length-2];
```

Or, sort the other direction:

```
myArray.sort(Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING);
var biggest:Number = myArray[0];
var nextBiggest:Number = myArray[1];
```

If your array is comprised of objects that have a numeric property, you can do the following:

```
var myArray:Array = [{name: "Hugh Jass", age: 5},{name: "Homer Simpson", age: 38}];

myArray.sortOn( ["age"], [Array.NUMERIC]);
```